# Force at least one pass of a do loop in legacy Fortran code

Tags: fortran, gfortran, do-loops

I have to compile an old fortran source already compiled using g77 but with the option `-fonetrip` to force execution of do loops at least once. I was not able to find this option or an equivalent in gfortran and the execution without this option aborts.
Any suggestions?

Probably I can go back to g77 but I do like if possible to use gfortran....

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour].

Comment: If this feature is neded only in a small number locations, wouldn't it be better to fix the code? This is something that was never standard, I think, not even in Fortran 66.

Comment: At best, gfortran can given you a warning if you have a zero-trip loop.  This requires explicit values for the do-loop `start` and `stop` such that `start > stop` and `step` is greater than zero.  I agree with @Vladimir that fixing the code would be the best objection, as g77 has no knowledge of many modern CPUs.

Comment: Thanks for your considerations but the code in object is about 1500 routines and I really do not know where this feature is used and habe some impact. Do loops are not using explicit indexes, they are calculated by the code at run time. What i really do not understand is why such option of g77 was removed in gfortran impacting a lot the old fortran sources. The -onetrip option was available (in different forms) on intel, hp, solaris etc.

Comment: The option was not removed in gfortran.  gfortran is a completely new Fortran compiler with nothing in common with g77. It is likely more correct to say no one has ever stepped forward to implement an `-fonetrip` (or similarly named option) for gfortran.

Comment: Thanks Steve. So I understand I am the first one asking for such option in gfortran... I can only hope more people will join me

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава From what I understand, the "zero trip count" for do loops has been explicitely introduced in F77. I assume that before F77 it was processor-dependant, but that the "one trip count" was a de facto convention.

Comment: Yes, you are the first person.  I've contributed patches for gfortran for 2 decades.  I do not recall seeing any such request and there is no open bug report.

Comment: The Intel Fortran compiler has a [-f66 option](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compatibility-options/f66.html), and they specify: *"DO loops are always executed at least once"*. 

Intel Fortran is free to download and use.

Comment: @PierU, AFAICT from reading F66 doc, it is impossible for a standard conforming F66 program to have a zero trip count.  For `do 10 i = m1, m2, m3`, F66 requires that `m1`, `m2`, and if present, `m3` are all greater than zero and `m1` is less than or equal to `m2`.

Comment: @PierU But that Fortran 66 constraint is very different from forcing a loop with otherwise zero count to be executed anyway.

Comment: @steve indeed you're correct (page 14 of https://archive.org/details/ansi-x-3.9-1966-fortran-66/page/14/mode/2up?view=theater)

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I know, but it's worth trying in case this is really some old, pre-F77, code.

Comment: The problem is that f66 check of do loop index was not made before entering the do body but at the end of the loop, supposing a good programming.., and this produced the behaviour of one trip do loop. When using do loops with calculated indexes and this are used to address areas of memory this behaviour become very important and able to change strongly the results during code execution. If there are no way with gfortran to optionally obtain such behaviour i will be forced to go back to a previous g77 version or, as suggested, use the intel compiler. Thanks to all of you for your help.